# $ \log_{\frac 32x_{1}}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{36x_{2}^{2}}\right)+\cdots+ \log_{\frac 32x_{n}}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{36x_{1}^{2}}\right).$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis, optimization, contest-math

Let $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$, $\ldots$, $x_{n}$ be $n$ real numbers in $\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{2}{3}\right)$. Find the minimal value of the expression: $ \log_{\frac 32x_{1}}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{36x_{2}^{2}}\right)+\log_{\frac 32x_{2}}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{36x_{3}^{2}}\right)+\cdots+ \log_{\frac 32x_{n}}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{36x_{1}^{2}}\right). $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression equals to $2n$ when all $x_i=\frac13$.
The expression cannot be less than $2n$ because of AM-GM inequality due to the following:
$$\frac{\ln\left(\frac12-\frac1{36x^2}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac32x\right)}=2\frac{\ln\left(\frac94x^2-\left(\frac32x-\frac1{6x}\right)^2\right)}{\ln\left(\frac94x^2\right)}\ge2$$